Blazor docker app, not getting the ssl certificates
I'm creating a webpage on blazor visual studio using kestrel hosting service. I'm executing it on an alpine server. Here's the code of program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
{

    serverOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate;
    });

    serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(80);
    serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(443, listenOptions =>
    {
        //listenOptions.UseHttps("./ssl/segundocert.pfx","1a2b3c4D.");
        listenOptions.UseHttps("/app/ssl/nginx.crt", "/app/ssl/nginx.key");
        //var certificate = new X509Certificate2("ssl/nginx.crt", "ssl/nginx.key", "1a2b3c4D.");
        //var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine("ssl", "nginx.pfx"),"1a2b3c4D.",X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        //listenOptions.UseHttps(certificate);
    });
});
...
var app = builder.Build();
...
app.Run();

The appsettings.json:
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    //"DefaultConnection": ...
    "DefaultConnection": ...
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:80"
      },
      "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:443",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "/app/ssl/nginx.crt",
          "Key" : "/app/ssl/nginx.key",
          "Password" : "..."
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

I have both certificates nginx.crt, .key (not using nginx, just gave them that name) in the same directory of the solution and the same one of the Dockerfile where is it written:
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

COPY nginx.crt ssl/nginx.crt
COPY nginx.key ssl/nginx.key

After all this I execute docker run --rm -it -p 80:80 -e ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=80 -p 443:443 -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=443 fibra_cert and the output is the next:
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (35ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/home/app/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed. For more information go to https://aka.ms/aspnet/dataprotectionwarning
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {dbb509b5-c376-4a51-aa91-527edafa3295} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Overriding address(es) 'http://*:8080'. Binding to endpoints defined via IConfiguration and/or UseKestrel() instead.
fail: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[11]
      Hosting failed to start
      System.NotSupportedException: The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.
         at System.Net.Security.SslStreamCertificateContext.Create(X509Certificate2 target, X509Certificate2Collection additionalCertificates, Boolean offline, SslCertificateTrust trust, Boolean noOcspFetch)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware..ctor(ConnectionDelegate next, HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions options, HttpProtocols httpProtocols, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, KestrelMetrics metrics)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<UseHttps>b__0(ConnectionDelegate next)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.Build()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass28_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.AnyIPListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.EndpointsStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(ListenOptions[] listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, Func`2 useHttps, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable`1 services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean abortOnFirstException, List`1 exceptions, Func`3 operation)
Unhandled exception. System.NotSupportedException: The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamCertificateContext.Create(X509Certificate2 target, X509Certificate2Collection additionalCertificates, Boolean offline, SslCertificateTrust trust, Boolean noOcspFetch)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware..ctor(ConnectionDelegate next, HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions options, HttpProtocols httpProtocols, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, KestrelMetrics metrics)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<UseHttps>b__0(ConnectionDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass28_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.AnyIPListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.EndpointsStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(ListenOptions[] listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, Func`2 useHttps, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable`1 services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean abortOnFirstException, List`1 exceptions, Func`3 operation)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /src/.../Program.cs:line 143
alpine1:/home/Temporal/FibraBonterra# docker run --rm -it -p 80:80 -e ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=80 -p 443:443 -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=443 fibra_cert
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (28ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/home/app/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed. For more information go to https://aka.ms/aspnet/dataprotectionwarning
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {d0d8e0f1-69aa-462b-8436-9233bea729bc} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Overriding address(es) 'http://*:80, https://*:443'. Binding to endpoints defined via IConfiguration and/or UseKestrel() instead.
fail: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[11]
      Hosting failed to start
      System.NotSupportedException: The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.
         at System.Net.Security.SslStreamCertificateContext.Create(X509Certificate2 target, X509Certificate2Collection additionalCertificates, Boolean offline, SslCertificateTrust trust, Boolean noOcspFetch)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware..ctor(ConnectionDelegate next, HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions options, HttpProtocols httpProtocols, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, KestrelMetrics metrics)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<UseHttps>b__0(ConnectionDelegate next)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.Build()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass28_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.AnyIPListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.EndpointsStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(ListenOptions[] listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, Func`2 useHttps, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable`1 services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean abortOnFirstException, List`1 exceptions, Func`3 operation)
Unhandled exception. System.NotSupportedException: The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamCertificateContext.Create(X509Certificate2 target, X509Certificate2Collection additionalCertificates, Boolean offline, SslCertificateTrust trust, Boolean noOcspFetch)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware..ctor(ConnectionDelegate next, HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions options, HttpProtocols httpProtocols, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, KestrelMetrics metrics)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<UseHttps>b__0(ConnectionDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass28_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.AnyIPListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.EndpointsStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at 
...
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(ListenOptions[] listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, Func`2 useHttps, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable`1 services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean abortOnFirstException, List`1 exceptions, Func`3 operation)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /src/.../Program.cs:line 143

I don't need to use Kestrel but update-ca-certificates wasn't working either. If I could have a guide to do this I would thank a lot.
Anyway, I need this to work. Would thank that someone told me why is failing me this.
Do I need to create containers and install the certificates there? How I can do it? What I need to change on my files?

First we need to clarify:
.crt is a certificate without key.
.pfx is a certificate with key which can be get from .crt+.key
The syntax is actually listenOptions.UseHttps("nginx.pfx","password"). So if use listenOptions.UseHttps("/app/ssl/nginx.crt", "/app/ssl/nginx.key"); , the "/app/ssl/nginx.key" is actually recognized as a string of password.

As the error said

System.NotSupportedException: The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.

Which means the app actually get /app/ssl/nginx.crt.  But it need "nginx.pfx".
You could get pfx using OpenSSL https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html with following cmd
openssl pkcs12 -export -in nginx.crt -inkey nginx.key -out nginx.pfx


Ok, now I have the problem that the certificate does not persit on the docker. Is there some question related? Or could you tell me how to do it?
